# remove an item from an integer array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to remove an element from an integer array given its index, are there any simple ways of accomplishing just that in VB.Net?

All I can find is `.RemoveAt()` for removing a string in an ArrayList, but none for an integer in an integer array.

```
Dim PossibleValues(8) As Integer
For x As Integer = 0 To 8
    PossibleValues(x) = x + 1
Next
```

Added the code, don't think it entails much as I am now trying to find ways to remove an element from the array PossibleValues

Comment: please provide your code that you try

Comment: Visual Studio is a development tool. It doesn't have arrays. What language are you writing your code in?

Comment: @KenWhite Visual Basic console app

Comment: Then your question should be tagged `vb.net`, not `visual-studio-2017`.

Comment: @Antu Added the code, not sure how much it'll help tho

Comment: If you need to add and remove items, don't use an array in the first place. Use a `List(Of Integer)`. Also, VB.Net array declarations use the index of the last element. So, including position 0, `PossibleValues(8)` creates an array with **9** elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with removing an item from an array is that it is of fixed size. So The simplest way is to convert the array to a list, ToList(), and then do the RemoveAt and then,  if you need to, convert it back to a new array with ToArray().

**EDIT**

```
Dim PossibleValues(8) As Integer
For x As Integer = 0 To 8
    PossibleValues(x) = x + 1
Next
Dim tempList = PossibleValues.ToList()
tempList.RemoveAt(1)
PossibleValues = tempList.ToArray()
```

Comment: Excuse my inexperience but I'm not sure what I am missing, there's still error indicated on the line where I used .RemoveAt `   Sub ArrayTest()
        Dim Array(1) As Integer
        Array(0) = 1
        Array.ToList
        Array.RemoveAt(0)
    End Sub`

Comment: My suggestion was something like this Dim PossibleValues(8) As Integer
        For x As Integer = 0 To 8
            PossibleValues(x) = x + 1
        Next
        Dim tempList = PossibleValues.ToList()
        tempList.RemoveAt(1)
        PossibleValues = tempList.ToArray()

Comment: @C.Tsang Please accept Paul Herbert's answer by clicking the the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.